# How to write a script that accepts input from a file or from stdin?

Tags: command-line, bash, stdin

How can one write a script that accept input from either a filename argument or from stdin?

for instance, you could use `less` this way. one can execute `less filename` and equivalently `cat filename | less`.

is there an easy "out of the box" way to do so? or do i need to re-invent the wheel and write a bit of logic in the script?

Comment: @PlasmaPower As long as the question is on-topic on SU, there is no *requirement* to ask on a different SE site. A lot of SE sites have overlap; generally we do not need to suggest an overlapping site unless the question is either off-topic (in which case, vote to migrate) or on-topic but not getting much of a response (in which case, the asker should flag for moderator-attention/migration, not cross-post).

Comment: Related: [How to read from file or stdin in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6980090/55075) at SO

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If the file argument is the first argument to your script, test that there is an argument (`$1`) and that it is a file. Else read input from stdin -

So your script could contain something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$1" ] && input="$1" || input="-"
cat $input
```

e.g. then you can call the script like

```
./myscript.sh filename
```

or

```
who | ./myscript.sh
```

**Edit**
Some explanation of the script:

`[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$1" ]` - If at least one command line argument (`$# -ge 1`) AND (-a operator) the first argument is a file (-f tests if "$1" is a file) then the test result is true.

`&&` is the shell logical AND operator. If test is true, then assign `input="$1"` and `cat $input` will output the file.

`||` is the shell logical OR operator. If the test is false, then commands following `||` are parsed. input is assigned to "-". The command `cat -` reads from the keyboard.

Summarising, if the script argument is provided and it is a file, then variable input is assigned to the file name. If there is no valid argument then cat reads from the keyboard.

Comment: what does   `&& input="$1" || input="-"`  do and why is it outside the `test` operator?

Comment: I've added an edit with some explanation which I hope will help.

Comment: What if the script has multiple arguments (`$@`)?

Answer (score 15):

`read` reads from standard input. Redirecting it from file ( `./script <someinput` ) or through pipe (`dosomething | ./script`) will not make it work differently.

All you have to do is to loop through all the lines in input (and it doesn't differ from iterating over the lines in file).

(sample code, processes only one line)

```
#!/bin/bash

read var
echo $var
```

Will echo first line of your standard input (either through `<` or `|`).

Comment: thanks! i choose the other answer because it suited me better. i was wrapping another script, and i didn't wanted to loop until all input recieved (could be a lot of input... would be wasteful).

Answer (score 5):

You don't mention what shell you plan on using, so I'll assume bash, though these are pretty standard things across shells.

## File Arguments

Arguments can be accessed via the variables `$1`-`$n` (`$0` returns the command used to run the program). Say I have a script that just `cat`s out n number of files with a delimiter between them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Parameters:
#    1:   string delimiter between arguments 2-n
#    2-n: file(s) to cat out
for arg in ${@:2} # $@ is the array of arguments, ${@:2} slices it starting at 2.
do
   cat $arg
   echo $1
done
```

In this case, we are passing a file name to cat. However, if you wanted to transform the data in the file (without explicitly writing and rewriting it), you could also store the file contents in a variable:

```
file_contents=$(cat $filename)
[...do some stuff...]
echo $file_contents >> $new_filename
```

## Read from stdin

As far as reading from stdin, most shells have a pretty standard `read` builtin, though there are differences in how prompts are specified (at the very least).

The [Bash builtins man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) has a pretty concise explanation of `read`, but I prefer the [Bash Hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) page.

Simply:

```
read var_name
```

### Multiple Variables

To set multiple variables, just provide multiple parameter names to `read`:

```
read var1 var2 var3
```

`read` will then place one word from stdin into each variable, dumping all remaining words into the last variable.

```
λ read var1 var2 var3
thing1 thing2 thing3 thing4 thing5
λ echo $var1; echo $var2; echo $var3
thing1
thing2
thing3 thing4 thing5
```

If fewer words are entered than variables, the leftover variables will be empty (even if previously set):

```
λ read var1 var2 var3
thing1 thing2
λ echo $var1; echo $var2; echo $var3
thing1
thing2
# Empty line
```

### Prompts

I use `-p` flag often for a prompt:

```
read -p "Enter filename: " filename
```

Note: ZSH and KSH (and perhaps others) use a different syntax for prompts:

```
read "filename?Enter filename: " # Everything following the '?' is the prompt
```

### Default Values

This isn't really a `read` trick, but I use it a lot in conjunction with `read`. For example:

```
read -p "Y/[N]: " reply
reply=${reply:-N}
```

Basically, if the variable (reply) exists, return itself, but if is's empty, return the following parameter ("N").

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to redirect stdin yourself:

```
if [ "$1" ] ; then exec < "$1" ; fi
```

Or if you prefer the more terse form:

```
test "$1" && exec < "$1"
```

Now the rest of your script can just read from stdin. Of course you can do similarly with more advanced option parsing rather than hard-coding the position of the filename as `"$1"`.

Comment: `exec` will try to execute the argument as a command which is not what we want here.

Comment: @Suzana_K: Not when it has no arguments, like here. In that case it just replaces file descriptors for the shell itself rather than a child process.

Comment: I copied `if [ "$1" ] ; then exec < "$1" ; fi` in a test script and it gives an error message because the command is unkown. Same with the terse form.

Comment: @Suzana_K: What shell are you using? If that's true it's not a working implementation of the POSIX sh command/Bourne shell.

Comment: GNU bash 4.3.11 on Linux Mint Qiana

Comment: @Suzana_K: I just tested with bash 4.3.33 and it works fine. I suspect you have a typo somewhere in the script or else some weird configuration getting processed. Are you entering the command interactively or in a script you're executing? Perhaps you could pastebin the script if you'd like me to look at it (or better yet, post a question here about why it's not working despite that it should).

Comment: Yes, that's weird. I'd also like to know the reason. I posted the output and the script to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/SuzanaK/04a1a66b2fe77f107013).

Comment: @Suzana_K This error occurs because `exec` is trying to open the file `hallo`, which does not exist. If you want to *write* to the file, flip the `<` to `>`.

Comment: @R.. Thanks. But `exec < somefile` doesn't make the shell read from the file by reading from stdin. Instead, it treats `somefile` as a shell script and executes it like `source` the script file. See https://superuser.com/questions/747884/how-to-write-a-script-that-accepts-input-from-a-file-or-from-stdin?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Tim: That's false. I don't know where you got that misconception but it's easily testable as well as clear from the specification.

Comment: My typo. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447317/674

Comment: @Tim: That's in an interactive shell that's reading commands from stdin, as opposed to a shell executing a script.

Comment: Bash manual doesn't say `exec < somefile` behaves differently in a noninteractive shell from an interactive shell. From what reference did you get it?

Comment: It's not that `exec < somefile` behaves any differently. It doesn't. It's that the *shell's basic command processing* behaves differently in interactive mode (reading commands from stdin) vs executing a script (reading commands from the script).

Answer (score 4):

You can also do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set variable input_file to either $1 or /dev/stdin, in case $1 is empty
# Note that this assumes that you are expecting the file name to operate on on $1
input_file="${1:-/dev/stdin}"

# You can now use "$input_file" as your file to operate on
cat "$input_file"
```

For more neat parameter substitution tricks in Bash, see [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Comment: This is fantastic! I'm using `uglifyjs < /dev/stdin` and it works wonderfully!

Answer (score 3):

use (or chain off of) something else that already behaves this way, and use `"$@"`

let's say i want to write a tool that will replace runs of spaces in text with tabs

`tr` is the most obvious way to do this, but it *only* accepts stdin, so we have to chain off of `cat`:

```
$ cat entab1.sh
#!/bin/sh

cat "$@"|tr -s ' ' '\t'
$ cat entab1.sh|./entab1.sh
#!/bin/sh

cat     "$@"|tr -s      '       '       '\t'
$ ./entab1.sh entab1.sh
#!/bin/sh

cat     "$@"|tr -s      '       '       '\t'
$
```

for an example where the tool being used already behaves this way, we could reimplement this with `sed` instead:

```
$ cat entab2.sh
#!/bin/sh

sed -r 's/ +/\t/g' "$@"
$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also keep it simple and use this code

---

When you create a script file *pass_it_on.sh* with this code,

```
#!/bin/bash

cat
```

You can run

```
cat SOMEFILE.txt | ./pass_it_on.sh
```

and all the contents of stdin will be simply spewed out to the screen.

---

Alternatively use this code to both keep a copy of stdin in a file and then spew it out to the screen.

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpFile=`mktemp`
cat > $tmpFile
cat $tmpFile
```

---

and here is another example, maybe more readable, explained here:

http://mockingeye.com/blog/2013/01/22/reading-everything-stdin-in-a-bash-script/

```
#!/bin/bash

VALUE=$(cat)

echo "$VALUE"
```

Have fun.

RaamEE

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way and POSIX compliant is:

```
file=${1--}
```

which is equivalent to `${1:--}`.

Then read the file as usual:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line" # Or: env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 echo "$line"
done < <(cat -- "$file")
```

Comment: POSIX doesn’t yet define `done < <(cat -- "$file")`-style process substitution.